# Show div inside a div if hovering

Tags: css

Would it be possible, with css only, that if I hover over the `.post` element the options show. If not I want it to be hidden.

```
<div class="post">

    <div class="author">
    Yxvasznalskje
    </div>

    <div class="options" style="display:none;">
    Report - Delete
    </div>

    <p>Message</p>

</div>
```

Comment: your question similar to this.. guess this will help too ->> stackoverflow.com/questions/17200141/animating-an-element-when-hovering-on-two-other-element-using-css

Answer (score 5):

Remove the inline `display:none;` and use `.post:hover .options` to select the inner div when the parent div is hovered:

```css
.options {
    display: none;
}

.post:hover .options {
    display: block;
}
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5w2s8/).